# Unity, terrain brushes in runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, brushes

so i want to create in unity a terrain in runtime. In the end it should be more procedural generated.
So far i could only found the direct manipulation of terrainData in changing the single vertices of the terrain, for example with perlinnoise. And i could find the usige of terrain brushes, but this is done with Editor tools, so it is NOT done with code during the runtime.

---

so this my question:
Is there a way to use terrain tools and brushes with code during runtime?

---

thank you a lot for the hints.

Comment: Doubtful.  It's not just the brushes but the property windows.  Like everything in Unity, the Terrain Tools have a rich set of property inspectors and inspectors aren't available at runtime.

Comment: Since your doing procedural generation vertex manipulation should be all you need. Brushes are for humans. Why would you want a program to use them in the first place?